# Blocking poll for new commits in remote

Tags: git

I have a git workspace and am running a script which executes `git pull --rebase` every minute.

But I am looking to be able to blocking poll for new commits in remote which then runs `git pull --rebase` right away, instead of being at most delayed by the minute.

Comment: Git doesn't provide a way to do what you want, but many forges provide a way to be notified when there are changes.  Are you using a forge, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If new commits in remote then triggers runs `git pull --rebase` locally right away, and you do not want the poll to be triggered as well, you could leave a "flag".

The new commits would not only trigger the `git pull --rebase` locally right away, it could also create a file (the "flag"), which indicates a pull --rebase was just done.

Your cron job (every minute) would then check if that flag file exists.
If it does, the poll routine would:

- *not* execute the `git pull --rebase` (since it was just done)
- delete the flag file (meaning one minute later, the poll routine would do a `git pull --rebase`)